I've got problem with animated react native horizontal flatlist
I'm trying to build a card carousel using flatlist + reanimated and i want to show edge of next slide inside of screen but next slide only appears when scrolling starts.
here is a gif to describe my problem
here is my main component
import { ImageSliderType } from '@/data/sliderData'
import React from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import SliderItem from './SliderItem'
import Animated, { useAnimatedScrollHandler, useSharedValue } from 'react-native-reanimated'

type Props = {
    itemList: ImageSliderType[]
}

const Slider = ({ itemList }: Props) => {
    const scrollX = useSharedValue(0);
    const onScrollHandler = useAnimatedScrollHandler({
        onScroll: (e) => {
            scrollX.value = e.contentOffset.x;
        }
    })


    return (
        <View>
            <Animated.FlatList
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                scrollEventThrottle={16}
                data={itemList}
                pagingEnabled
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                horizontal
                onScroll={onScrollHandler}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => <SliderItem item={item} index={index} scrollX={scrollX} />} />
        </View>
    )
}

export default Slider

and my items component
import { Text, Image, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { ImageSliderType } from '@/data/sliderData'
import Animated, { Extrapolation, interpolate, SharedValue, useAnimatedStyle } from 'react-native-reanimated'

type Props = {
    item: ImageSliderType,
    index: number,
    scrollX: SharedValue<number>
}

const { width } = Dimensions.get("screen")
const SliderItem = ({ item, index, scrollX }: Props) => {

    const rnAnimatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        return {
            transform: [
                {
                    translateX: interpolate(
                        scrollX.value,
                        [(index - 1) * width, index * width, (index + 1) * width],
                        [-width * .25, 0, width * .25],
                        Extrapolation.CLAMP
                    ),
                },
            ]
        }
    }
    )
    return (
        <Animated.View style={[styles.itemCnt, rnAnimatedStyle]}>
            <Image source={item.image} style={{ width: 300, height: 500 }} />
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
        </Animated.View>
    )
}

export default SliderItem

const styles = StyleSheet.create(
    {
        itemCnt: {
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            gap: 20,
            width: width,

        }
    }
)


and data
import { ImageSourcePropType } from "react-native";
export type ImageSliderType = {
title: string;
image: ImageSourcePropType;
description: string;
}
export const ImageSlider =
[
    {
 title: 'Nullam enim ligula', 
 image: require('@/assets/images/sliderImages/4.jpg'),
description: 'Duis vitae libero risus. Sed vitae ligula at eros ultr',
    },
    {
 title: 'Nullam enim ligula', 
 image: require('@/assets/images/sliderImages/4.jpg'),
description: 'Duis vitae libero risus. Sed vitae ligula at eros ultr',
    },
    {
 title: 'Nullam enim ligula', 
 image: require('@/assets/images/sliderImages/4.jpg'),
description: 'Duis vitae libero risus. Sed vitae ligula at eros ultr',
    },
    {
 title: 'Nullam enim ligula', 
 image: require('@/assets/images/sliderImages/4.jpg'),
description: 'Duis vitae libero risus. Sed vitae ligula at eros ultr',
    },
    {
 title: 'Nullam enim ligula', 
 image: require('@/assets/images/sliderImages/4.jpg'),
description: 'Duis vitae libero risus. Sed vitae ligula at eros ultr',
    },
]


basically what i was trying to do was show first slide in center of screen and show only a tiny bit of next one biside it
